# Multiple Radio Buttons that change Submit onclick location.href...possible syntax error

Tags: javascript, forms, onclick, radio-button, form-submit

I'm using http://www.somacon.com/p143.php javascript for radio buttons to change the submit onclick location.href depending on which radio button is selected. But I think I may have an issue with my syntax as the button isn't working properly (I don't think it is pulling the value from the radio buttons properly). Thanks in advanced!

Here is the code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
// return the value of the radio button that is checked
// return an empty string if none are checked, or
// there are no radio buttons
function getCheckedValue(radioObj) {
if(!radioObj)
    return "";
var radioLength = radioObj.length;
if(radioLength == undefined)
    if(radioObj.checked)
        return radioObj.value;
    else
        return "";
for(var i = 0; i < radioLength; i++) {
    if(radioObj[i].checked) {
        return radioObj[i].value;
    }
}
return "";
}

// set the radio button with the given value as being checked
// do nothing if there are no radio buttons
// if the given value does not exist, all the radio buttons
// are reset to unchecked
function setCheckedValue(radioObj, newValue) {
if(!radioObj)
    return;
var radioLength = radioObj.length;
if(radioLength == undefined) {
    radioObj.checked = (radioObj.value == newValue.toString());
    return;
}
for(var i = 0; i < radioLength; i++) {
    radioObj[i].checked = false;
    if(radioObj[i].value == newValue.toString()) {
        radioObj[i].checked = true;
    }
}
}
//-->
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form name="radioExampleForm" method="get" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
<p><label for="number0"><input type="radio" value="http://www.google.com" name="number"     id="number0"> Zero</label>
&nbsp;<label for="number1"><input type="radio" value="http://www.ebay.com" name="number" id="number1"> One</label>
&nbsp;<label for="number2"><input type="radio" value="http://www.gamestop.com" name="number" id="number2"> Two</label>
&nbsp;<label for="number3"><input type="radio" value="http://www.amazon.com" name="number" id="number3"> Three</label>
&nbsp;<label for="number4"><input type="radio" value="http://www.usatoday.com" name="number" id="number4"> Four</label>
<p>
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='+getCheckedValue(document.forms['radioExampleForm'].elements['number']);" value="Show Checked Value">

ORIGNAL SUBMIT CODE THAT MADE AN ALERT BOX RATHER THAN location.href = <input type="button" onclick="alert('Checked value is: '+getCheckedValue(document.forms['radioExampleForm'].elements['number']));" value="Show Checked Value">

</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a syntax error.

Change it to:

```
onclick="window.location.href = (getCheckedValue(document.forms['radioExampleForm'].elements['number']));"
```